# Are there any images of SOOS?

Tags: payload

SOOS--Stacked Oscar On Scout--was what it was called when the 1985 decision was made to replenish the [Operational (Oscar) Transit](https://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/techdigest/pdf/V05-N04/05-04-Danchik.pdf) constellation with unflown first-production models. Early Oscars were flown one at a time on [Scout rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_(rocket_family)), but by the time that they decided to replenish the constellation, Scouts could now carry two stacked atop one another: [SOOS](https://ethw.org/US_Launches_Navigation_Satellite).

[image]

Are there any images of this payload?

Comment: Is it possible to add a few links for some of these items that you think readers unfamiliar with the topic might find helpful? (e.g. [eoPortal](https://earth.esa.int/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/t/transit), [jhuapl](https://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/techdigest/pdf/V05-N04/05-04-Danchik.pdf), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_(satellite))) Thanks!

Comment: Transit related: [Is Transit 5B-5 a.k.a. Oscar 2 really “still kind of 'active'”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21144/12102) and [What's the spiral pattern on this satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27649/12102) and [What was the design failure that Johns Hopkins Applied Physics Laboratory is alluding to?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27658/12102)

Comment: also [jhuapl](https://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/techdigest/pdf/V05-N04/05-04-Danchik.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this image of a SOOS payload in the document *[The Navy Navigation Satellite System (TRANSIT)](https://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/techdigest/pdf/V05-N04/05-04-Danchik.pdf)*

[image]

The first part of this quote actually refers to the image in the question, which is also from the linked document.

> In the stacked configuration on the booster, the upper spacecraft
> (shown in the background) looks like a normal OSCAR. The lower
> spacecraft (in the foreground) is surrounded by a cradle that carries the load of the
> upper spacecraft during launch. The cradle remains permanently
> attached to the lower spacecraft as shown
>
> Figure 7 shows the stacked configuration
> on the booster fourth stage with the solar panels removed from the
> upper spacecraft.